# VITE Buildiing phase: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'vite-plugin-commonjs'

Tags: deployment, build, vite, esmodules

I'm trying to dpeloy my first vite project but i'm getting the following error:

```
9:32:18 AM: $ npm run build
9:32:18 AM: > entertainment-app@0.0.0 build
9:32:18 AM: > vite build
9:32:18 AM: failed to load config from /opt/build/repo/vite.config.js
9:32:18 AM: error during build:
9:32:18 AM: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'vite-plugin-commonjs' imported from /opt/build/repo/vite.config.js.timestamp-1688387538947-29a5bd1b45ad8.mjs
9:32:18 AM:     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
9:32:18 AM:     at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
9:32:18 AM:     at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
9:32:18 AM:     at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
9:32:18 AM:     at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
9:32:18 AM:     at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
9:32:18 AM:     at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
9:32:18 AM:     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
9:32:18 AM:     at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
9:32:18 AM: ​
9:32:18 AM: build.command failed
```

i used the vite-pluggin-commonjs which is not supported during building phase, so i also installed the rollup/plugin-commonjs as it is recommended on the the commomjs npm page:

here's my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import commonjs from "vite-plugin-commonjs";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), commonjs()],
});
```

and the rollup.config.js:

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

export default {
  input: "src/main.jsx",
  output: {
    dir: "output",
    format: "cjs",
  },
  plugins: [commonjs()],
};
```

As its my first time deplying the website i'm not sure what the error means, i also didn't find any similar errors online

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13775